# INSERT key behavior in PyCharm reversed

Tags: pycharm

This may sound strange, but the behavior for the INSERT key is reversed, but only in PyCharm. If I have it off, meaning that the cursor is not a block and just a single line, the behavior is acting like INSERT is turned on.

If I have INSERT turned on, meaning my cursor is a block, the behavior is like it should be when INSERT is turned off.

This is only in PyCharm that I am seeing this behavior.

Has anyone else seen this, it is a minor annoyance, just wondering if anyone has seen this and how they took care of it.

Comment: What have you tried doing to solve this problem? Have you restarted pycharm, did you create a new project? Did you reinstall it?

Comment: I have restarted PyCharm. I have not created a new project or uninstall and reinstall, I will try those things and return and report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling PyCharm took care of this. Thanks for the suggestion @Games Brainiac

The actual problem was that I had selected the "Use Block Caret" option under Settings/Editor/Appearance. With this option it looks like the INSERT key is reversed. Turning this off, fixed the problem